# Datadog how do i change a monitor to a single alert with no recovery

Tags: datadog, datadog-dashboard

So i currently have a monitor set up that sends an alert, but after 5 mins it also send a recovery alert. What i wanted to find out was is it possible to have a monitor that only sends the alert but no recovery alert.

I need a one off alert on error thats it.

Answer (score 11):

To extend onto draav's answer, your notification template should look like this when notification needs to be sent only in case of alert

```
{{#is_alert}}

This is my alert content!

@john@doe.com
{{/is_alert}}
```

This approach can be further extended when we want to notify different users for different type of notifications.

Below example sends alert notification to john@doe.com and recovery notification to holly@doe.com.

```
{{#is_alert}}

Something went wrong!

@john@doe.com
{{/is_alert}}

{{#is_alert_recovery}}

Things are back to normal!

@holly@doe.com
{{/is_alert_recovery}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Put your message inside a conditional variable: https://docs.datadoghq.com/monitors/notify/variables/?tab=is_alert#conditional-variables

The message will only be sent on alert, and not for any other status changes

Comment: not sure how that would work. I just want the alert to be sent and then dont worry about the recovery alert.

Comment: As in the example in the docs draav linked, putting your notification handle between`{{#is_alert}}` and `{{/is_alert}}` means that the notification only gets sent when the alert is triggering, not when it's recovering.